# Translate one line of Perl to PHP

Tags: php, perl

I am translating a file from Perl to PHP, but I need help with this line:
`@stuff_unique = grep !$list{$_}++, @stuff;`.
I know `stuff_unique` and `stuff` are arrays.

Comment: It is finding all the unique lines of the array `@stuff` and storing it in `@stuff_unique` (removing duplicates).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common Perl idiom, described in [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3F)

With this construct, `@stuff_unique` will end up with a list of items that were seen at least once in `@stuff`; in other words, it is left holding only unique values, in the sense that there will be no repeats.  The way it works is this:

A hash, in Perl, is like an associative array with unique keys.  `%list` is such a hash.  `$list{something}` is an element in that hash named 'something'.  Its value can be whatever you place in it.

`grep` iterates over the items in `@stuff`.  For each item in `stuff`, that item is used as a hash key in the `%list` hash.  The `++` increments the value for that corresponding hash element.  So if `@stuff` contained "1, 2, 1", then on the first iteration a hash element named "1" would be created.  It has no value, which translates to Boolean false.  The `!` in front reverses the Boolean sense.  So on that first iteration, the false value for the '1' hash element is evaluated as true, so that element passes through to `@stuff_unique`.  Finally, post-increment takes place, so the value held in the `1` hash element increments to 1.

On the second element, the 2 has also not yet been seen, so it passes through, and its corresponding hash element is also incremented to 1.

On the third iteration, a '1' is seen again.  `$list{1}` is already equal to `1`, which is a true value.  !true is false; so this one doesn't pass through to `@stuff_unique`.

One by one the elements in `@stuff` will be tested in this way; detecting if they've been seen before, and if they haven't, they pass through to `@stuff_unique`.

PHP provides a function called [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), which should do the same thing for you.  It would be used like this:

```
$stuff_unique = array_unique($stuff);
```

Fortunately for the Perl people, this is a linear-time operation.  Unfortunately for the PHP people, this is implemented internally by sorting the input array, and then iterating over it, skipping duplicates along the way.  That means it's a `O(n + n log n)` operation (simplified to `O(n log n)`), which is to say, its implementation can't scale as well as the common Perl idiom.

Comment: @Olsi Is there something that I must add or clarify for the answer to be worthy of a thumb's-up, and/or an "accept" checkmark?

Comment: @DavidO OP didn't have enough rep when he first posted the question.

Comment: Ah, I get it.  I thought he was saying he didn't find justification for doing so. :)

Comment: No, the answer was more clear and scientific than I expected.

Comment: @mob I appreciate your noticing the mistake in how I phrased it. I believe I've now corrected that.

Answer (score 2):

The joy of using php closures,

```
<?php

$stuff = array(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3);

$list = array();
$stuff_unique = array_filter($stuff, function($_) use (&$list) {
  return !$list[$_]++;
});

print_r(array_values($stuff_unique));
```

or

```
<?php

$stuff = array(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3);
$stuff_unique = array_keys(array_flip($stuff));

print_r($stuff_unique);
```

or

```
$stuff_unique = array_values(array_unique($stuff));
```

Comment: I like this because it is a more direct translation of the Perl idiom, presumably with similar time-complexity characteristics.  +1.

Comment: @DavidO yes, but is a PITA in php. I guess `foreach` performs far better and is more familiar to php community.

Comment: With respect to that first sentence, when one arrives with certain expectations, he won't be disappointed when they prove true. ;)